# Change directory before running local script

Tags: shell, ansible

I want to change the directory before running a local script on a remote node. Script doesn't allow `chdir` as a argument. How to do that?

```
---
- hosts: centos
  remote_user: kk
  sudo: true
  tasks:
   - name: Run local script on  remote node
     script: /home/Ansible/VM/monitor/space.sh > space_result.txt
     args:
      chdir: /home/Ansible   # something like that
      creates: space_result.txt
```

Comment: Can the "script" argument be rewritten as: cd /home/Ansible && /home/Ansible/VM/monitor/space.sh > space_result.txt ?

Comment: Maybe you want a `copy` task followed by a `command` task, or modify the script to do the `cd` command at it's start...

Comment: @twalberg  -  Playbook was a success, File got copied but no output file.
 
     - name: Run local script on  remote node
         copy:
           src:  ~/Ansible/VM/monitor/space.sh
           dest: /home/kk/space.sh
           owner: kk
           mode: 0744
       - command: /home/kk/space.sh > space_result.txt
         args:
         chdir: /home/kk/Ansible/
         creates: space_result.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227939/change-directory-before-running-local-script#comment69663895_41227939) ("*Playbook was a success, File got copied but no output file.*"):

Redirection does not work in the `command` module. You should use [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) instead:

```
- name: Ensure local script is copied to the remote node
  copy:
    src: ~/Ansible/VM/monitor/space.sh
    dest: /home/kk/space.sh
    owner: kk
    mode: 0744

- name: Run copied script on the remote node
  shell: /home/kk/space.sh > space_result.txt
  args:
    chdir: /home/kk/Ansible
    creates: space_result.txt
```